# Loop to Replace Matching Values

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm looking for an easy and elegant way to accomplish this.
So if I have dataset `x` and relationship is `A -> B -> Z -> Y` and `D -> H -> G`, I would like to create dataset `y`. Unfortunately, they are not necessarily in order:

```
> x <- data.frame(
+     from = as.character(c("A", "E", "B", "D", "H", "Z")), 
+     to = as.character(c("B", "E", "Z", "H", "G", "Y")))
> 
> y <- data.frame(
+     from = as.character(c("A", "E", "B", "D", "H", "Z")), 
+     to = as.character(c("Y", "E", "Y", "G", "G", "Y")))
> 
> x
  from to
1    A  B
2    E  E
3    B  Z
4    D  H
5    H  G
6    Z  Y
> y
  from to
1    A  Y
2    E  E
3    B  Y
4    D  G
5    H  G
6    Z  Y
```

I have a fairly large dataset (currently 500k rows; will grow in the future) and actually care about the performance; I'm not sure if there are any other ways to do this without a for-loop or even to vectorize/parallelize the process.
I'm thinking about splitting and removing all rows where `from == to` or creating an indicator to skip certain rows so the loop does not have to go through the entire dataset each time.
I'd also like to know what the breakpoint should be if I do create a loop; I'm not sure how to define when the loop should stop.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a case for `igraph`

Comment: @akrun Never heard of it before and documentation seems pretty massive - would you have a suggestion on where or which function to start looking? Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` to create a grouping variable by comparing the adjacent elements of 'to' and 'from' and change the values in 'to' the `last` element of 'to'

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
    group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(lead(from, default = last(from)) != 
      as.character(to), default = TRUE))) %>% 
    mutate(to = last(to)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  from   to    
# <fctr> <fctr>
#1 A      D     
#2 B      D     
#3 C      D     
#4 E      E
```

Comment: I was actually looking at this function but I wouldn't know the end result (y$to) is "DDDE" without looking at the table, so how would that work?

Comment: @creativename  Updated the post

Comment: Impressive! I love the dplyr solution. It seems like you know your ways around `cumsum` :)
But I didn't mean to imply that they're always in sequential order - could you take a look at my updated example?

Comment: @creativename  Thanks, the updated expected output is not clear to me

Comment: Sorry about not being clear in the original question; I was trying to create a better example. One relationship is still `A -> B -> C -> D` but the table is not necessarily in order. I just added few rows that also go from `F -> G -> H`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be achieved using `lag` from `dplyr` and `fill` from `tidyr` as:

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>% arrange(from) %>%
  mutate(samegroup = ifelse(from == lag(to), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(samegroup == 0 | is.na(samegroup), row_number(), NA)) %>%
  fill(group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(to = last(to)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-samegroup, - group)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  from  to   
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 A     D    
#2 B     D    
#3 C     D    
#4 E     E    
#5 F     H 
#6 G     H
```

## Data used

```
x <- data.frame(from = as.character(c("A", "B", "F", "C", "G", "E")), 
   to = as.character(c("B", "C", "G", "D", "H", "E")), 
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Seems like I have a lot of flaws in my reproducible example to represent real data - I can't arrange by "from" because they're not in alphabetical order; I updated the example. I agree this would have worked otherwise :(

Comment: @creativename Understood. Yes we need to look for another logic.